# Different raw output on the same command

Tags: powershell, winapi, pty

I am spawning a `powershell` process via `CreateProcess()` as well as using `ConPTY` `CreatePseudoConsole()`.

I would assume that the raw output must be the same on each command call, but it isn't.

To show the issue, I spawn `powershell` and run the `hostname` command 4 times in a row. And run this a couple of times. Here are the results:

```
OUT "\u{1b}[25l\rEXPECTED_PROMPT>  \u{1b}[93mhostname\u{1b}[m\r\n>> \u{1b}[23X\u{1b}[7;27H\u{1b}[?25h\rEXPECTED_PROMPT>  \u{1b}[93mhostname\u{1b}[m\r\n>> \u{1b}[23X\r\nDESKTOP-NNSSIDQ\r\n\u{1b}[25lEXPECTED_PROMPT>  \r\n>>\u{1b}[16X\u{1b}[10;19H\u{1b}[?25h"
OUT "\u{1b}[?25l\rEXPECTED_PROMPT>  \u{1b}[93mhostname\u{1b}[m\r\n>> \u{1b}[23X\r\n\u{1b}[?25hD\u{1b}[25l\rDESKTOP-NNSSIDQ   \r\nEXPECTED_PROMPT>  \r\n>>\u{1b}[16X\u{1b}[13;19H\u{1b}[?25h"
OUT "\u{1b}[?25l\rEXPECTED_PROMPT>  \u{1b}[93mhostna\u{1b}[m\r\n>> \u{1b}[21X\u{1b}[13;25H\u{1b}[?25h\rEXPECTED_PROMPT>  \u{1b}[93mhostname\u{1b}[m\r\n>> \u{1b}[23X\r\nD\u{1b}[25l\rDESKTOP-NNSSIDQ   \r\nEXPECTED_PROMPT>  \r\n>>\u{1b}[16X\u{1b}[16;19H\u{1b}[?25h"
OUT "\u{1b}[?25l\rEXPECTED_PROMPT>  \u{1b}[93mhostname\u{1b}[m\r\n>> \u{1b}[23X\r\n\u{1b}[?25hD\u{1b}[25l\rDESKTOP-NNSSIDQ   \r\nEXPECTED_PROMPT>  \r\n>>\u{1b}[16X\u{1b}[19;19H\u{1b}[?25h"
```

```
OUT "\rEXPECTED_PROMPT>  \u{1b}[93mhostname\u{1b}[m\r\n>> \u{1b}[23X\r\nD\u{1b}[25l\rDESKTOP-NNSSIDQ   \r\nEXPECTED_PROMPT>  \r\n>>\u{1b}[16X\u{1b}[10;19H\u{1b}[?25h"
OUT "\u{1b}[?25l\rEXPECTED_PROMPT>  \u{1b}[93mhostname\u{1b}[m\r\n>> \u{1b}[23X\u{1b}[23C\r\n\u{1b}[?25hDESKTOP-NNSSIDQ\r\nEXPECTED_PROMPT> \u{1b}[25l\rEXPECTED_PROMPT>  \r\n>>\u{1b}[16X\u{1b}[13;19H\u{1b}[?25h"
OUT "\u{1b}[?25l\rEXPECTED_PROMPT>  \u{1b}[93mhostname\u{1b}[m\r\n>> \u{1b}[23X\r\n\u{1b}[?25hD\rDESKTOP-NNSSIDQ   \r\nEXPECTED_PROMPT>  \u{1b}[25l\r\n>> \u{1b}[16;19H\u{1b}[?25h"
OUT "\u{1b}[?25l\rEXPECTED_PROMPT>  \u{1b}[93mhostname\u{1b}[m\r\n>> \u{1b}[23X\r\n\u{1b}[?25hDESKTOP-NNSSIDQ\u{1b}[25l\r\nEXPECTED_PROMPT>  \r\n>>\u{1b}[16X\u{1b}[19;19H\u{1b}[?25h"
```

```
OUT "\rEXPECTED_PROMPT>  \u{1b}[93mhostname\u{1b}[m\r\n>> \u{1b}[23X\r\nD\rDESKTOP-NNSSIDQ   \r\nEXPECTED_PROMPT>  \u{1b}[25l\r\n>> \u{1b}[10;19H\u{1b}[?25h"
OUT "\u{1b}[?25l\rEXPECTED_PROMPT>  \u{1b}[93mhostname\u{1b}[m\r\n>> \u{1b}[23X\u{1b}[23C\r\n\u{1b}[?25hD\rDESKTOP-NNSSIDQ   \r\nEXPECTED_PROMPT>  \u{1b}[25l\r\n>> \u{1b}[13;19H\u{1b}[?25h"
OUT "\u{1b}[?25l\rEXPECTED_PROMPT>  \u{1b}[93mhostname\u{1b}[m\r\n>> \u{1b}[23X\r\n\u{1b}[?25hDESKTOP-NNSSIDQ\r\n\u{1b}[25lEXPECTED_PROMPT>  \r\n>>\u{1b}[16X\u{1b}[16;19H\u{1b}[?25h"
OUT "\u{1b}[?25l\rEXPECTED_PROMPT>  \u{1b}[93mhostname\u{1b}[m\r\n>> \u{1b}[23X\r\n\u{1b}[?25hDESKTOP-NNSSIDQ\r\nEXPECTED_PROMPT>  \u{1b}[K\u{1b}[?25l\u{1b}[165C\r\n>>\u{1b}[17;19H\u{1b}[?25h"
```

Note:

In most cases, I see that it repeats the command several times in the output. Like more than 4 times, sometimes + prompt.

But sometimes, on some command, it repeats the output all from the first command to this one.

And as I noticed, sometimes the output differs from performance resources.

Comment: Please show a [mcve].